# the relation between the meaning of the word "strip"

Tags: word-meaning

strip is comic book, is that related with other meanings such like that in the sentence
: `The children stripped off their clothes and jumped into the river.`

Comment: [Merriam-Webster's: "Stripped"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stripped). Look at definition #1, *to remove clothing*.

Comment: @Walter I think OP is asking whether those two definitions derive from some common idea.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it should be answerable by a dictionary. If @Jim is correct and this is an etymology question, it would be more appropriate to be asked on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.  To strip something off is to remove something in strips. Strips are long thin pieces of something which is exactly the shape of the piece of paper needed to hold a comic strip.

Some notes:

- A comic *book* is not a strip. A comic strip is what is printed, in
  the newspaper for example, consisting of a series of frames that
  could fit on a long strip of paper.
- Stripping off clothes is a figurative phrase used when the clothes
  come off so fast it seems like they must be coming off in torn
  strips.